# I pasted this jsfiddle and it doesn't open the popup window

Tags: html, popup

I have pasted a jsfiddle into my webpage and it doesn't work.  [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaulKrugley/Ywus5/).  Pasted the CSS and javascript into the appropriaate places.  There seem to be no errors on the console related to the link or popup.

All the link seems to do is to reload the current page.

Here is my HTML :

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                <!-- POST -->
                {% for entry in entries %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">                        
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="media media-clearfix-xs-min">
                          <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="lesson.html">
                              <span class="media-object icon-block bg-default"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                            <h3 class="media-heading h4"><a href="{{ url_for('write_response', id=entry.id) }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>

                            <p class="small text-muted">
                              <!-- <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> time since post -->
                              <a href=""  class="popup-link-1">Open PopUp</a>
                                <div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-1">
                                    <div class="close">X</div>
                                        <div class="top">
                                            <h2>Sample Header</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="bottom">
                                            <p><h1>Sample Text</h1></p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                              <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <a href="{{ url_for('public_user_page', userID=entry.userID) }}">{{entry.user_name}}</a>
                              <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> {{entry.date_posted}}                                
                            </p>
                            {% for tag in entry.tagList %}
                                <span class="label label-default">{{tag}}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <em>No entries!</em>
                {% endfor %}        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here, I should have tested more.

I thought I had pasted the javascript in the right file, but I didn't.  Once I pasted the js in the right file, it worked fine.